# Is there any difference of meaning between 'I am happy to be going home' and 'I am happy to go home'?

Tags: meaning, differences

I am happy to be going home.
I am happy to go home.

I use both for a same meaning, but I was wondering if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference, yes.

***I am happy to go home*** states that you are pleased with the notion of going home, whenever it might be. The concept of going home is favorable to you and the feeling is consistent.

> Q: ***Is it depressing when the school term ends?***
>
> A: ***Maybe a little. But I am happy to go home.***

As opposed to ***I am happy to be*** **going** ***home***, which implies that said behavior is imminent. The action is underway and in progress. You're *in the process* of returning to your place of residence.

> Q: ***Are you excited that you're leaving today?***
>
> A: ***Yes, very much. I'm happy to be going home.***

Comment: *I am happy to go home* can also be short for “I would be happy to go home [if you’re offering that option]”